# Avoid blinking of script

Tags: javascript, cookies, shopify

I am using a Javascript to push divs down to display a `Notice`. However I find it irritating that it blinks on load and that makes it not very smooth. Is there a way to work around this? I can make it smooth by adding `slideDown(1000);`, then there is no blinking, but I don't want it to slideDown on every page, I just want it to be displayed without blinking.

[Live test](http://eldecosmetics.com)

Ideas?

```css
#fixed {
    position: relative;
}

#notice {
    background: #31384a;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999912312399;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;

    .exit {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;

        img {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

JS

```js
var clearCookie = function () {
    var result = $.removeCookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification');
    if (result) {
        alert('Cookie removed, please reload.');
    } else {
        alert('Error: Cookie not deleted');
    }
};

var closeCookie = function () {
    $("#notice").slideUp(400, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('#fixed').animate({
        top: 0
    }, 400);
    $.cookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification', 'Notified', {
        expires: 7
    });
};

// Bind the buttons
$("#clearCookie").on("click", clearCookie);
$(".exit").on("click", closeCookie);



// Now display the cookie if we need to
if ($.cookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification') == null) {
    $('#notice').show();

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        $('navmenu, navmenu-mobile, #fixed').css({
            top: $('#notice').outerHeight()
        });
        if ($('#notice').outerHeight() == $('#fixed').css('top')) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten a chance to read all your code, but a simple fix would be to use `slideDown(0)`

Basically, that will slide your div down in 0 milliseconds, which would achieve the same thing as `.show()` but would also stop the blinking

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it seems to not work. I am not using service side cookies, I am using Shopify so it is on client side. I added .slideDown(0); instead of .Show();

Comment: I don't understand, .slideDown(0); is client side. I didn't mention server side cookies either.